# How can I install Kallithea on Windows Server 2022 with Python 3.11?

Tags: python, kallithea

I installed current Python (3.11).
Then `pip install pywin32 --upgrade`, created folders and `python -m venv ...` called `activate` in Scripts folder and `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`.
Finally `pip install kallithea`. Waiting full of anticipation...

**ImportError: Python version not supported**

Is it still possible to get Kallithea running on Windows (how?) or can you actually consider it dead now and have to use something else?

Adam Jenča is right - Kallithea uses an outdated FormEncode:

> Collecting FormEncode<1.4,>=1.3.1 (from kallithea)
> Using cached FormEncode-1.3.1.tar.gz (197 kB)
> Installing build dependencies ... done
> Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Comment: Can you show the complete error traceback?

Comment: The problem is not with Kallithea, the problem is with a different package called FormEncode, which in  version 1.3.1 (the one required by kallithea) supports only Python 3.0 to 3.2 (if i read the messy code correctly).

Comment: I think if Kallithea uses an obsolete package that prevents installation Kallithea itself is obsolete. I can't build ancient Python to get it running. :( I don't understand why a package manager like pip tries to install broken software - it's just pathetic. I think we just use our old server untill until it passes away and use Git or something else... :(